# Set background for row in table dynamic using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I06KN.png)

I have table dynamic binding. I want to set Background for column Grade if it have * word.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered span11" >
    <tr id="test" class="header" >
        <th  ng-repeat="header in plansHeader"  >{{header}}</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="value in plansList">
        <td  ng-repeat="header in plansHeader" id="{{header}}"  ng-class="{Overrange: value[header].contains('*')}">
            <div  ng-bind-html="value[header]"></div></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

My Js code.

```
$scope.plansHeader=[];
if(res.length>0){
    $scope.plansList  = res;
    var plansHeader=[];
    for(var key in res[0]){
        if(key.indexOf("$")<0)
        {
            plansHeader.push(key)
        }
    }
    $scope.plansHeader = plansHeader;

}
```

Array: 0

{LOT_NO: "CRB-602", LINE: "S21", ProdDate: "180101-13:39", Grade: "*B", Grades: "0",…}
1
:
{LOT_NO: "", LINE: "S22", ProdDate: "180101-13:40", Grade: "*Qu", Grades: "0",…}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
ng-class="{Overrange: value[header].indexOf('*') > -1}"
```

**More Info**

A note about contains is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#compatNote_1). Generally, it's not available:

> In Firefox 18 - 39, the name of this method was contains(). It was renamed to includes()...

On that note, [use of includes is not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility); so I don't recommend that either, unless you know that your user base won't require it.

Comment: It's ok. But all row of Grade need set Background:red. You can i see my picture. All row color have * word. But row of Grade need have background:red. Not color.